# Is there a way how to recover deleted rows in Mysql Database?

Tags: mysql, recovery

I accidentally deleted records in MSQL database and there is no backup no rollback transaction and i reallly want to recover deleted data back is there any tool to help ? how could i do  ? please help me .

Comment: If you didn't backup the DB, you probably have no way to recover.  A great mantra in most computer work..."Save Early, Save Often".

Comment: There is no way at all that you can recover those records unless you have a backup.

Comment: Check if binary logging is enabled. `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE %log%`. And check the status of variable `log_bin`. If it's on then you can restore your lost data.

Comment: Yes. Use the backup you made.

Comment: i don't have any back up and there is no binary log enable . my bad day @@!

Answer (score 0):

Is it `MySQL` or `MSSQL` they both are not same. `MSSQL` stands for `SQL Server` but by any means for you to recover deleted data either you should have taken a recent full/differential **backup** in place (or) if you have maintained **transaction log**. Then yes possible to get back your data by restoring from your backup (or) by reading from transaction log. Else, No there is no way to recover those data.

Comment: Hi Rahul , it is MySQL . in saw on sql server we can get data back using tools apexsql but i don't know how to do on MySQL .

Comment: @KolikaChan, No any tool will help unless you either have backup or trans log maintained.

Comment: there is no transaction log we never enable it . my bad day @@! . thanks you .

Answer (score 0):

For InnoDB tables, if binary logs are enabled, one could use:

`mysqlbinlog path_to_binary_log_file > query_log.sql`

If binary logs are not enabled, there is a recovery [tool](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/02/20/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-an-innodb-tablespace/) provided by Percona which may help.

Created a [script](https://github.com/VanagaS/mysql-innodb-autorecover) to automate the steps from the Percona tool which recovers the deleted rows (if exist) and provides SQL queries to load the data back into database.

Please note:

> The time between the deletion of rows and the database stop is
> crucial. If pages are reused you can’t recover the data.